# Deserialize Json with unknown fields / properties

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize the following Json using Newtonsoft.Json.

Json:

```
{
   "response":{
      "lines":{
         "day":{
            "day_data":{
               "available":1,
               "rating":"1"
            },
            "2422424":{
               "data_id":"2422424",
               "category":"breakfast"
            }
         },
         "night":{
            "night_data":{
               "available":2,
               "rating":"2"
            },
            "353533":{
               "line_id":"353533",
               "category":"dinner"
            },
            "3433":{
               "line_id":"3433",
               "category":"dinner"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

C# Code:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(jsonSource);
```

The problem arises with the fields such as 2422424,353533 etc which are generated dynamically.

RootObject:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Response response { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public Lines lines { get; set; }
}

public class Lines
{
    public Day day { get; set; }
    public Night night { get; set; }
}

public class Day
{
    public Day_Data day_data { get; set; }
    public _2422424 _2422424 { get; set; }
}

public class Day_Data
{
    public int available { get; set; }
    public string rating { get; set; }
}

public class _2422424
{
    public string data_id { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
}

public class Night
{
    public Night_Data night_data { get; set; }
    public _353533 _353533 { get; set; }
    public _3433 _3433 { get; set; }
}

public class Night_Data
{
    public int available { get; set; }
    public string rating { get; set; }
}

public class _353533
{
    public string line_id { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
}

public class _3433
{
    public string line_id { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
}
```

Please let me know how to identify them while deserializing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not deserialize an undefined structure into a defined structure. Obviously this is not possible as fixed classes cannot be amended with new properties at runtime.

Anonymous objects to the help, sample from JSON.NET's documentation:

```
var definition = new { Name = "" };

string json1 = @"{'Name':'James'}";
var customer1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json1, definition);

Console.WriteLine(customer1.Name);
// James

string json2 = @"{'Name':'Mike'}";
var customer2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json2, definition);

Console.WriteLine(customer2.Name);
// Mike
```

[Link to JSON.NET samples](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Samples.htm)